# UILabel truncation " ..." (space + ...)  instead of "..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

So I am trying to implement `UILabel` with `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`.

So, for example if the text is `"StackOverflow is the best website for programmers"`, it gets truncated as `"StackOverflow is the best..."`

It needs to be `"StackOverflow is the best ..."` (Space + ...)

Is there any easy way to implement this ??

Any easy implementations other than subclassing & overriding `drawRect`, and/or playing around with the frames, (if it character limit frame size, stop it and append " ...")  ??

Look forward to interesting implementations !

Comment: Are you able to share why this behavior is a requirement? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: I am requiring this because it looks a lot cleaner and goes well with the app. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Apple does not provide any API for this. You have to write your own implementation. I would calculate the width of the UILabel with the current font, see if it exceeds the maximum width, if it does, truncate text, otherwise present text normally.